# Is pasting a private key into the Jenkins web portal secure?

Tags: security, jenkins, encryption, ssh, ssh-keys

In Jenkins, I've only every seen one method for storing a private ssh key credential.

This method is recommended by everybody:  Open the Jenkins server web portal in a web browser, go to `Credentials`, and under `Add Credentials`, select `SSH Username with private key`, paste the private key into the web page, and hit `ok`.

This, I assume, uses an HTML form to send the private key in a POST request over HTTPS to the Jenkins server, which then saves the private key locally on the server's disk.

**The problem**:  The top voted answer to the question "[How to securely send private keys?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101560/how-to-securely-send-private-keys)" states that a private ssh key can only be secured by **not transmitting it at all**.

**My question**: is pasting a private key into the Jenkins web portal and transmitting them over HTTPS actually secure?  If not, what is the best way to get a private key into the Jenkins credentials?

Comment: Are you trying to connect Jenkins with GitHub? or other service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**in situ**

Using the web UI for this is probably secure *enough* for almost every use case, and is hard to beat with respect to convenience.

Nevertheless, generating private keys where they are needed is certainly good advice, and is definitely possible with Jenkins.  One approach:

- SSH into the Jenkins server, and generate the keys
- Run some groovy in the script console to create the Jenkins credential
- Exfiltrate the public key
- Delete the generated keys on the server

In this example, on the Jenkins server both `$HOME` and `$JENKINS_HOME` point to `/var/jenkins_home`, and the keys are generated in `~/temp`.

---

**Generate the key on Jenkins server**

```
ssh jenkins@my.jenkins.server
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "some-meaningful-label" -f "./my-in-situ-key"
```

This creates `my-in-situ-key` and `my-in-situ-key.pub` in `/var/jenkins_home/temp`.

---

**Create the Jenkins credential**

In Jenkins script console:

```java
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain

def domain = Domain.global()

def store = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0].getStore()

def privateKeyString = new File('/var/jenkins_home/temp/my-in-situ-key').text
def keySource = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey.DirectEntryPrivateKeySource(privateKeyString)

def privateKeyCredential = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey(
    CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
    "temp-stack-overflow-key",      // id
    "jenkins",                      // username
    keySource,                      // private key
    "",                             // passphrase
    "Temporary Demo Key"            // description
)

store.addCredentials(domain, privateKeyCredential)
"Credential Added"
```

Test the credential before cleaning up.

---

**Clean up**

Grab the public key and **be sure to delete the private key** on your way out the door.

```
cat ~/temp/my-in-situ-key.pub
rm -rf ~/temp
```

---

[Relevant Javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/ssh-credentials/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/sshcredentials/impl/BasicSSHUserPrivateKey.html)

Answer (score 1):

The second way to secure a private key is to use for *only one* specific usage: you can then easily revoke that key at any time, regenerate one dedicated for that access, and register the new key.

That being said, copy/pasting the key to the Jenkins Web GUI with an encrypted transmission between your client and the Jenkins server is deemed secure enough, especially in an enterprise LAN (Local Area Network) environment, to your own Jenkins server.

If you are talking WAN, over the internet, then... this is not *completely* bullet-proof safe. But for some Jenkins jobs (unless those jobs reveal sensitive data), it should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No". If you want an SSH identity in the Jenkins server, generate a distinct public/private key there and use it for that one purpose exclusively.